# run a string containing python code in python.

Tags: python, parsing

I have a string containing some if/else statements, for example:

```
self.y = 10

x = "if 1 > self.y: DO-Something else: Do-something-else"
```

is it possible to run this code while the program is opperating. (pseudocode explination)

```
x = "if 1 > self.y: DO-Something else: Do-something-else"

runprogram(x)
```

Thanks!

Comment: exec() will run code :). but the use of it is usually a big NO NO. see here for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158117/use-of-exec-and-eval-in-python   but I can sum it up in two words "security issues"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html) to execute your code in string.

But use `exec` with care :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use exec (eval would do too, in some situations).

But you need to be very careful, especially if the code to be evaluated (or executed) will be input by the users.